# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'createSentryMetroSerializer' before initialization

Tags: react-native, sentry

I am trying to implement sentry into my React Native project and am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'createSentryMetroSerializer' before
> initialization

I have followed the setup instructions here:

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/

In my App.js I have added:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react-native';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://code.ingest.sentry.io/code',
});
```

Even when I comment out this I still get an error.

Comment: Seems something from sentry is utilized before sdk initialization.., can you attach the codes for the initialization and usages?

Comment: @VickyAhuja I have added the code. When I comment it out there is still this issue because the package is installed even with no initialization code.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You can report issues here ~ https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues

Answer (score 2):

in your metro.config.js file,move

`const { createSentryMetroSerializer } = require("@sentry/react-native/dist/js/tools/sentryMetroSerializer");`

to first line of file